# How to create a function to count items from a set and store counts in an array parallel to one containing related items?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am having trouble completing one of the last assignments in my semester-long high school-level programming class. I have been assigned to create a JavaScript program which counts the amount of time different ZIP codes appear in a set and output parallel arrays containing the zip codes and their counts. I am having difficulty getting the values to output. I believe that the respective zips and counts aren't being entered into their arrays at all.

I'm not looking for an original solution to the problem. I'd just like someone to tell me why my code isn't working, and possibly what I can change in my code specifically to fix it.

Usually I would never ask for help like this. I actually took the class last semester and now that I'm at the end of the year I have the option of completing it to earn college credit. I have never been the best at working with functions, and that remains true now. In the code below are all the moving parts I'm allowed to work with. I know it looks messy and rudimentary, but it's all I know. I'd appreciate it if any answers use only the sorts of things I used in my code. Another note, I am required to use functions for 'all identifiable processes', but I'm pretty sure my instructor only cares about the final product, so I'm not sure that the functions really matter, even if they could help.

```
var records = openZipCodeStudyRecordSet(),
    uniqueZips = [],
    zipCounts = [],
    output = "";

function project62Part1() {
    table = document.getElementById("outputTable");

    function countZips(zip) {
        var currentZip,
            count;
        while (records.readNextRecord()) {
            currentZip = records.getSampleZipCode();
            if (zip === currentZip) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }   

    function processZip(zip) {
        var currentZip;
        while (records.readNextRecord()) {
            currentZip = records.getSampleZipCode();
            for (i = 0; i < uniqueZips.length; i++) {
                if (uniqueZips[i] === "") {
                    uniqueZips.push(currentZip);
                    zipCounts[i] = countZips(currentZip);
                    break;
                } 
                if (zip !== uniqueZip[i]) {
                    uniqueZips.push(currentZip);
                    zipCounts[i] = countZips(currentZip);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function createOutput(string) {
        for (i = 0; i < uniqueZips.length; i++) {
            string += "<tr><td>" + uniqueZips[i] + "</td><td>" + zipCounts[i] +
                    "</td></tr>";
        }
        return string;
    }


    processZip();
    output = createOutput(output);
    table.innerHTML = "<tr><td>Zip Code</td><td>Count</td></tr>" + output;
}
```

The output is supposed to be additional rows of zips and counts added to a table that is already set up on the page. There are no important technical errors in the code.

This is to be accomplished through the function processZip, which is meant to add respective zip and count into table rows. However, it appears as though the zip and count arrays its getting info from haven't had anything put into them by the other functions. I don't know if it is because of error in calling the functions, or what's in the functions themselves.

The HTML page this is connected to calls the function project62Part1().

Comment: do you have an input and wanted output to get an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is kind of all over the place but here's the logic you ideally want to follow:

1. Loop over each record in your table (outer loop) to get the zip code.
2. Declare an 'isFound' variable and set it to false
3. For each iteration of the outer loop, loop over your entire array of zip codes (inner loop).

3a. If you get a match, set isFound to true, increment your zipcode counter += 1 on the same index (since they're parallel arrays)

3b. If, at the end of your inner loop, isFound is still false, add the zipcode to your array of zip codes, and add a new array element to your zip code counters setting it to 1.

Since your zip code array and your zip code counter are parallel arrays to each other, when isFound is false, you are creating entries in both arrays, keeping them parallel to each other.

If, on 3a isFound is true, you are on the index of the zip code array that the zip code belongs to, so it should be the same index for your counter array.

In your current process zip function, the first condition will never be true, because starting out, your array size is 0 and after you start populating that array, you will never have an empty string (unless, of course, the zip code itself was an empty string)

The second if statement you have that checks if `zip !== uniqueZip[i]` - you are only checking that current value of `uniqueZips` and ignoring every other value in the array, so you will almost always have the second condition as true

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with the newer JavaScript language and syntax and your item was a good candidate for me to try out. 
I did approach the code a little differently such as making the use of a Set for the unique values. Saves on code by not having to check and see if the value exists because the Set will never allow duplicate values in.

```
var uniqueZips = new Set();
const zipcodes = [21060, 22422, 25541, 43211, 21060, 22422, 22422, 43211, 43211, 43211];

function project62Part1() {

    function processZipCodes() {
      for(let index in zipcodes){
        // We add every value because a SET will only allow you to add it once.
        uniqueZips.add(zipcodes[index]);
      }
    }

    // Structure our zipcode data information
    function organizeZipCodeData() {
      let response = {data:[]};

      uniqueZips.forEach(function(zip) {
        response.data.push( { 'zipcode':zip, 'appears': countZipAppearances(zip) })
      });

      return response;
    }

    function countZipAppearances(zip) {
      // Default to zero even though you never expect an undefined
      let count = 0;
      zipcodes.forEach(function(zval) {
        if (zip === zval) {
          count++;
        }
      });

      return count;
    }

    function showZipcodeInformation(data){
      for (var index in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
          var entry = [data[index]][0];
          console.log(entry.zipcode, entry.appears);
        }
      }
    }

    // UI CONTENT: Construct the UI view from the data
    function generateHtmlView(data){
      let htmlview = "<table><tr><td>Zip Code</td><td>Count</td></tr>";

      for (var index in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
          var entry = [data[index]][0];
          htmlview+="<tr><td>"+entry.zipcode+"</td><td>"+entry.appears+"</td></tr>";
        }
      }
      htmlview += "</table>";

      console.log(htmlview);
      return htmlview;
    }

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Call to gather the zipcodes
    processZipCodes();

    // Call to organize the zipcode data
    let output = organizeZipCodeData();

    // See what we have in the organized data
    showZipcodeInformation(output.data);

    // See what we have in the html content
    generateHtmlView(output.data);
}

// Initiate the process
project62Part1();
```